# Why won't this form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Here's my code - I've checked my development log and it shows that the form is not being submitted.

I know I can do it by adding a submit tag, but I don't want to do this. I want it to submit automatically when I check the box.

What am I missing?

```
 <h>
<%= form_tag do %> 
<%= check_box_tag(:zagat_status) %>
 <%= label_tag(:zagat_status, "Zagat status") %>
 <% end %>
 </h>
```

**Javascript code**

```
<script type="javascript">
          $(function() {
    $("h").click(function() {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
    });
});
      </script>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript? What made you think it would magically submit itself?

Comment: To expand on the last comment, you'll need to fire off a form submit event when the checkbox is clicked. see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: I am, I pasted above the javascript i'm using. As you can tell, I'm very new to this so apologies for the simplicity of the question.

Comment: @JoshBodah: using w3schools as reference is frowned upon on this site. :)

Comment: There's nothing in that JS related to form submission, you just check a check box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Rails built-in AJAX functionality](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) (i.e. add `remote: true` to the `form_tag`).

```
<%= form_tag('/YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE', remote: true) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:zagat_status, true) %>
  <%= label_tag(:zagat_status, "Zagat status") %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("form").on('change', "input:checkbox", function(){
      $("form").submit()
    })
  })
</script>
```